# How to add approximate location from the end user to appear below product name?

Tags: magento2, product-page, locations

We are developing a Rental based Website with Magento 2.

In the Rental product, there are options for both shipping and pickup.

**If the product is pickup, then we want to show the approximate location of store from the end user under the product title as below screenshot.**

How can I do that?

[image]

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot here. What exact you want.

Comment: @RaviSoni, Added screenshot, please check and suggest me

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you a file.

Override below file for implementation:

> /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml

You can override this file in your custom theme.

And you can implement there you customization for locations.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please suggest me how to display the approximate location from the end user as in the attached screenshot?

Comment: You can set the product attribute there. And get here in the above file.